# How to push object into array firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to push an object into an array that is stored to the user in firebase.
I have this. It starts on click

```
  function savetodb() {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if(user) {
      db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get().then(doc => {
        const saveditems1 = doc.data().saveditems
 saveditems1.push({
          Name:'Test',
          Price:'Test',
          Link:'https://www.test.com'
        })
        
    });
    }
    else {
return alert('no')
    }
})
```

There is no errors in the console, but it doesn't add anything to the user's array.

Here is the on click function

```
     <button id="savedb" onclick='savetodb()'>Save For Later</button>
```

I don't know why It isn't adding to the array. Here is how it is stored in firestore
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore arrays don't support index'd arrays that you can push into, behind the scenes they use ordered lists and you must invoke an `arrayUnion` Firestore function.
It is important to note that the document does not need to exist if you use `set:merge` methods as `arrayUnion` will generate the array if it does not exist.

```
const data = {
        Name: 'Test',
        Price: 'Test',
        Link: 'https://www.test.com'
    }
doc.set({
    saveditems: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(data)
},
{merge:true});
```

To remove items from an array, you must pass the exact value back to an `arrayRemove` function.

```
const data = {
        Name: 'Test',
        Price: 'Test',
        Link: 'https://www.test.com'
    }
doc.update({
    saveditems: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(data)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.push()` isn't suitable for the task; you'd have to use `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion` and  `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove` to perform array-manipulation in Firestore.
See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-v8_11.

Something alike (assuming that data-type `object` is being supported):

```
doc.update({
    saveditems: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
        Name: 'Test',
        Price: 'Test',
        Link: 'https://www.test.com'
    })
});
```

There's also `admin.firestore.FieldValue` counterparts, but these are for NodeJS.